# To find interval in which geometric series is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

The given series is

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2x)^n$

Now common ratio here is 2x. So series is convergent if $-1<r<1$ which gives me interval $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$. But textbook stated answer to be this closed interval. Anyone please confirm this?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: That must be a mistake since for $x=\frac{1}{2}$ we get $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}1$, which diverges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. The area of convergence is $(-\frac 12, \frac 12)$, as for $x = \pm \frac 12$, we have the series 
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1, \qquad \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n $$
which both do not converge.

Comment: Yeah ! Thanks i knew it